# How to display your custom app on home page

Tags: forms, view, menu, odoo-14

I tried to make a menu for my custom app but it doesn't display to home page. Any idea on how to make it happen? I wanted to display my app beside to installed apps. I am using Odoo 14.

This is my form:

```
<record id="view_custom_module_form" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.custom.module.form</field>
            <field name="model">custom.model</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <form string="Custom" create="false" delete="false" edit="false">
                    <sheet>
                        <group>
                            <group>
                                <field name="name" readonly="1"/>
                                <field name="number" readonly="1"/>
                            </group>
                        </group>
                    </sheet>
                </form>
            </field>
        </record>
        
        
        <record id="action_custom_module" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Custom Module</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">custom.model</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="view_custom_module_form"/>
        </record>
```

And this is my menu:

```
        <menuitem
            name="Custom" 
            id="menu_custom_menu"
            sequence="1"
            web_icon="custom_module,static/description/icon.png"
            groups="base.group_user,base.group_partner_manager"/>
        
        <menuitem id="submenu_custom_menu"
            name="Custom"
            parent="menu_custom_menu"
            action="action_custom_menu"
            sequence="1"/>
```

And I wanted to display my custom app icon here:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solved it. This is what I did to show my app.
I put the sequence on it. Make sure you already make your form view so that your custom module will show up.

```
<menuitem id="menu_custom_form_root"
              name="Custom FOrm"
              sequence="9"/>

    <menuitem id="menu_form"
              name="Forms"
              parent="menu_custom_form_root"
              action="action_forms"
              sequence="9"/>
```